# Getting slash is a directory error while running echo in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to output following ascii character art every time my terminal loads:

```
   __  __                  _
  / / / /___  ____ _____ _(_)
 / / / / __ \/ __ / /
/ /_/ / / / / /_/ / /_/ / /
\____/_/ /_/\__,_/\__, /_/
                 /____/
```

So I added following at the end of `.bashrc`:

```
echo "   __  __                  _ 
  / / / /___  ____ _____ _(_)
 / / / / __ \/ __ `/ __ `/ / 
/ /_/ / / / / /_/ / /_/ / /  
\____/_/ /_/\__,_/\__, /_/   
                 /____/      "
```

And it prints:

[image]

It seems that it is misinterpreting slash in ascii art as escape sequence, that why it is printing `-bash: /: Is a directory`. How can I get rid of it? If I add something simple to `.bashrc`, like `echo "Hello World!!"`, it does not print this error message.

Comment: What if you replace `"` with `'`? With `"` you get interpolation, with `'` not so much.

Comment: or escape the 2 back ticks in the code with a back slash. The shell interprets the code as print multi-line string + "whatever commands are inside `` " +  more multi-line string. 2 back ticks are basically the same as `$()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the single quote instead:

```
echo \
'   __  __                  _ 
  / / / /___  ____ _____ _(_)
 / / / / __ \/ __ `/ __ `/ / 
/ /_/ / / / / /_/ / /_/ / /  
\____/_/ /_/\__,_/\__, /_/   
                 /____/      
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
text=(
    '   __  __                  _'
    '  / / / /___  ____ _____ _(_)'
    ' / / / / __ \/ __ `/ __ `/ /'
    '/ /_/ / / / / /_/ / /_/ / /'
    '\____/_/ /_/\__,_/\__, /_/'
    '                 /____/'
)

printf '%s\n' "${text[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

For a multi-line text literal, a HereDoc is very appropriate:

```sh
# Use a quoted heredoc 'marker' to disable expansion of backticks
cat <<'LOGO'
   __  __                  _
  / / / /___  ____ _____ _(_)
 / / / / __ \/ __ `/ __ `/ /
/ /_/ / / / / /_/ / /_/ / /
\____/_/ /_/\__,_/\__, /_/
                 /____/
LOGO
```

Un-quoted heredoc marker:

```sh
cat <<EOF 
hello `echo world`
EOF
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

Quoted heredoc 'marker':

```sh
cat <<'EOF'
hello `echo world`
EOF
```

Output:

```
hello `echo world`
```